# Magento2: JStree Style CSS is not loaded properly

Tags: magento2, cache, js-css

JStree Style CSS is not loaded properly

**404 error:**

> pub/static/version1580100386/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jstree/themes/default/style.css

Please help.

Comment: whether minification or merging css is included?

Comment: Yes, Minified and Merging CSS